# NPE when loading a file in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to load a file into a parser class that I've written but I keep getting a NPE on the following line. I've changed the file path around but it doesn't help.
The location of the dataset.csv file is src/res/raw

File location is defined as:

```
private static final String FILE = "/res/raw/dataset.csv";

File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource(FILE).getFile());
```

The line above keeps throwing an NPE

Comment: Rather than trying to use a resource as a File, why not just use it as a resource (URL or InputStream)? I suspect an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) may be present here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are not files, or `Files.` They could be inside a JAR file for example.

You should use the `URI` returned by `this.getClass().getResource(FILE),` or the `InputStream` returned by `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(FILE),` directly.

Comment: Can you explain this please, I don't follow you.

Comment: I have explained it. You'll have to tell me what part of 'you should use the URI ... or InputStream ... directly' you don't understand. I've even written some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `getResource()` method uses the classpath to find resources. If the file you are looking for is not in the classpath, it will not be found and you will get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Ok, what is the solution?

Comment: @EJP's answer contains the key - use this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(FILE) which will return you an InputStream to the file you need. Make sure that the file is in your class path - either amongst your .class files, or in the same jar.